# What bonuses do(n't) apply to Rend?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage

Rend says

> If it hits with two or more natural attacks in 1 round, a creature with the rend special attack can cause tremendous damage by latching onto the opponent's body and tearing flesh. This attack deals an additional amount of damage, but no more than once per round. The type of attacks that must hit and the additional damage are included in the creature's description. The additional damage is usually equal to the damage caused by one of the attacks plus 1-1/2 the creature's Strength bonus.

I'm wondering if the following bonuses to damage rolls apply to a Rend?

- Power Attack says "gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls".
- Inquisitor's Judgement says "gaining a +1 sacred bonus on all weapon damage rolls"
- Holy says "deals an extra 2d6 points of damage against all creatures of evil alignment"

Do those get added to the Rend?

And what about a bonus to one of the attacker's claws only, e.g. if one of the claws that hit had Bane on it, does the Bane damage get added a second time?

Comment: It's going to depend on the wording of the specific feature that grants you Rend; all of them specify separately how the damage works (even though most of them are quite similar). Which Rend are you talking about?

Comment: @KRyan 
This is for an Eidolon:
"An eidolon learns to rip and tear the flesh of those it attacks with its claws, gaining the rend ability. Whenever the eidolon makes two successful claw attacks against the same target in 1 round, its claws latch onto the flesh and deal extra damage. This damage is equal to the damage dealt by one claw attack plus 1-1/2 times the eidolon’s Strength modifier."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons:

> An eidolon learns to rip and tear the flesh of those it attacks with its claws, gaining the rend ability. Whenever the eidolon makes two successful claw attacks against the same target in 1 round, its claws latch onto the flesh and deal extra damage. This damage is equal to the damage dealt by one claw attack plus 1-1/2 times the eidolon’s Strength modifier. The eidolon must possess the claws evolution to select this evolution. The summoner must be at least 6th level before selecting this evolution.

I wouldn't think it gets any other bonuses from melee feats. Rend isn't an attack, it's just bonus damage.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's for an Eidolon's ability, I would say that all bonuses that apply normally would apply to the additional damage dealt by Rend. So if your damage is normally (say) 2d4 and it's got a +2 strength bonus, then the extra rend damage would be 2d4+3. Even for Power Attack, Judgement, whatever, treat it *almost* as though you'd landed a third attack.